# Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found, in a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

In my wordpress site I get the error "Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found"

php-xml not being installed on the server can cause the issue but it's already installed (I'm using Centos)

I've also added "extension=dom.so" to the php.ini but it's still not working

Thanks

Comment: did you restart the server software?

Comment: check the output of phpinfo() served through the webserver. make sure ext/dom is listed. if its not listed, find the location to the correct php.ini to use and enable it there. then restart the webserver.

Comment: Ok I can see the phpinfo now on the webpage, there is no mention of the dom extension in there, although like I said in the actual file extension=dom.so is there and not disabled anywhere. Also php-xml and php-dom are already installed. I reinstalled using yum but no difference. I'm really at a loss here.

Comment: The file /etc/php.d/dom.ini is there which contains extension=dom.so, though it's not listed as being parsed in the phpinfo

Comment: Does anyone know a solution please thanks

Answer (score 8):

DOM is PHP module. This error usually occur when we not have this php module installed. 
[Dom listed in phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzR8Q.png)
you can get this information by running phpinfo() function on any php file.

There are few way to debug and fix this issue. 
- first install php-xml package

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

then after restarting your apache server

```
sudo service apache restart
```

If still this issue is not fixed. 
check your php version and install appropriate php-xml module for it
for example: for php 7.0

```
apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Comment: Missing `php5.6-xml` on my end. Thanks!